# Python Support in Vim 8 in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: python, 17.04, vim

I'm currently running Ubuntu Zesty. However the default Vim package does not support Python? I've already installed `vim-nox` as well.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:        17.04
Codename:       zesty

$ vim --version | grep python
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
```

Does the default Vim package support the Python plugin, or did I mess up my installation, or miss something else here?

Comment: See this: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10242/vim-8-0-python-support

Comment: Can you try installing vim-gnome/vim-gtk and see if they still have the python support enabled.

Comment: `vim-nox` should support `python3`, but not `python`. Python 2 support was dropped in 17.04. What does `vim.nox --version` report?

Comment: Thanks a lot people. 

Just realize my vim is pointing to `vim.gtk3` instead of `vim.nox` through `sudo update-alternatives --config vim`